# The screen freezes till the function returns

Tags: java, android, freeze

i need to use a code to check if i have internet access before i push files to the database .. 
this is the code i am using. it works fine if i have internet connection but if not it freezes for like 6 or 7 seconds

```
public static boolean isInternetReachable() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
    int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
    return  (returnVal==0);
}
```

i want it  to push files - file by file - to database and i want to check if the internet is working or not everytime

Comment: Do it on a separate thread.

Comment: There are several easy to use apis present for checking whether the device has network connection or not. Try to find and use those instead of this approach.

Comment: What if google is down ? (yes, it can happen, you know)

Answer (score 2):

To check if a user is connected to the internet, use this.

```java
public boolean hasInternetConnection() {
  ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  return manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

Your screen freezes because you're performing a long running task (uploading files) on the main thread which can lead to your app not being responsive. You'll have to move that operation off the main thread, either by using an AsyncTask, RxJava, or Coroutines (Kotlin).
[See this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr#Avoiding)

Comment: thanks bro but you didn't get me i run this code only to tell if i have internet access if it is true i ll upload the files ..
but your function returns true even if i dont have internet access like i have a Wifi and i am connected to it but the cable is not plugged .. in this case it returns true which it should be false

Answer (score -1):

```
 Handler hander = new Handler(this);
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //do what you want
  },2000L);
```